# Parsing SOAP object array in Android

Tags: java, android, soap, ksoap2, android-volley

I'm getting an `SOAP` response like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
           <GetAllCodesAndLevels
              xmlns="http://www.myCodesWeb.com/">
              <GetAllCodesAndLevelsResult>[['1/12/2014 10:50:00 PM',1.5,2.2,55.9],['1/16/2014 11:52:00 AM',88.88,88.12,88.99],['1/18/2014 10:12:00 PM',12.3,12.4,12.2]]</GetAllCodesAndLevelsResult>
           </GetAllCodesAndLevels>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm looking for a way to extract this array and build `ArrayList<Code>` from `Code` Class:

Each `SOAP` array element in the response  - `['1/12/2014 10:50:00 PM',1.5,2.2,55.9]` suppose to be a `Code` object.

```
 public class Code {

        public double code1;
        public double code2;
        public double code3;
        public int date;

public Code (double code1, double code2, double code3, int date) {
        super();
        this.code1= code1;
        this.code2= code2;
        this.code3= code3;
        this.date = date;
    }

    }
```

How can I do it? do I need to use `ksoap2` library or maybe extract it to `Json`, or maybe use `Volley` library?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `SaxParser` to extract the codes http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/.
And the handler would look as follows:

```
private class Parser extends DefaultHandler
{
    String codes;
    String tag;

    public String getCodes()
    {
        return codes;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
    {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
        tag = qName;
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException
    {
        if (tag.equals("GetAllCodesAndLevelsResult"))
        {
            codes = new String(ch, start, length);
        }
        else
        {
            super.characters(ch, start, length);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use something similar to this solution to extract the separate codes.
[Java: Is there any simpler way to parse array elements from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642575/java-is-there-any-simpler-way-to-parse-array-elements-from-string).